# CHAR(4) or INT To store a 4-digit year in MySQL, i.e., 2015

Tags: mysql, sql

Just wondering what the best practise is here.  I want to create a table with a column for year. Should I set it to CHAR(4) or INT?

Comment: You could use a `DATE` and ignore the day/month part, but otherwise an integer makes more sense.

Comment: It will work with CHAR/VARCHAR but it is better to use INT/SMALLINT.

Comment: Are you already storing the full `DATE` in another field?  What's the purpose of storing the year separately?

Comment: Don't use `char` to store numbers. With an `int` or `smallint` you can at least prevent storing something like `foo` into that column (you still can't prevent out-of range values due to MySQL's lack of check constraints).

Comment: The answers provided are only acceptable assuming that you are only storing the year, or that you have some good reason for separating the year out as well as storing the full date.  Best practice depends on usage.

Comment: @GoatCO: in a data warehouse set up, it's reasonable to have separate year, month, day, etc. columns in your date dimension (or equivalent). Otherwise, I'd say it's also reasonable to have int for year if the column really is only a year. Storing it as a date is misleading and opens the door to storing details that aren't needed or are ignored (but it's not obvious that they are).

Comment: @GoatCO Why do you think a full date is stored in the first place? I don't see any reference to that in the question. The question is to store a year, no more, no less.

Comment: @siride Agreed, I didn't mean it's unacceptable, just that 'best practice' can't be determined without knowing more about the usage.

Comment: @GoatCO: I probably shouldn't have responded to you specifically. Others were saying that the OP should just use date without consideration of the reasons why you wouldn't necessarily want to do that.

Comment: @GolezTrol I don't know whether it is or not, hence my comment. Someone asking about int vs char for storing year may be barking up the wrong tree altogether, I just wanted to point out that it may be the wrong approach to start with, and was hoping for clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would choose an integer type. You can make it SMALLINT if you like to make it use less space, SMALLINT  can hold year values up to 32767 and uses only two bytes.

But anyway, a year is a number, and you may want to compare it as such. To me it makes more sense to use integer than character for that.

Answer (score 0):

**Int** is faster for **where** (queries) from **char**.

Comment: Are you sure? Fixed size fields are pretty fast in MySQL anyway, and Char(4) has the same data size as an integer.